# Clarification regarding a JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a scenario in my website where a user who logs in might have the permissions to modify a database.

So when a user logs in right now I'm creating a connection and use it for running the queries.

Is there a way to remove write permissions for a jdbc connection, so if every time the user who is not suppose to modify the database tries to run a query which tries to update a database he is not able to do so.

Comment: Remove the write permissions for the user you're using to connect with yout database in the configuration.

Comment: How do I remove the write permissions for a jdbc connection while creating a connection

Comment: Again, the permissions are not for the JDBC connection, are from the user you use to connect with your database e.g. (<JDBC_URL>, **user**, password). That **user** has write permissions, just remove those permissions in your database.

Comment: Every user of the database does not have access to connect to the database.I'm having a jdbc connection pool from which I'm reading and writing the data in tables.

Answer (score 2):

The permissions are handled by the database and not by the jdbc connection.
If you want to restrict a user that has access to the jdbc connection, then you have to do it inside the database.

But you always have the possibility to check the Queries before executing them. By doing this you can filter out the unwanted queries.
BTW, it is a good idea to provide a bunch of predefined queries where the user can choose from and disallow free user defined queries.

In the case you are using one common database user for all website users you will have to do the permission checks by yourself, e.g. by filtering the queries.

Comment: Every user of the database does not have access to connect to the database.I'm having a jdbc connection pool from which I'm reading and writing the data in tables and BTW if I try checking the queries before executing them then I would have to change the code in more than 300 places.

Comment: Or the other direction which I was thinking was I maintain 2 connection pools. One which has read & write access and the other which would have only read access. Is that possible.

Comment: yes, this would be another possibility, but again, you will have to do the mapping from website users to database users by yourself